# EXCEL VBA - Setting a dynamic Filename based on range values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a VBA newbie attempting to save a filename based on range values. The information in the cells change everytime a Userform updates the information. I keep getting a Run-time error "1004" when the macro is run. This is the code I'm using:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\ME\Desktop\TEST" &  Sheets("Fail").Range("B8").Value & Sheets("Fail").Range("C8").Value & Sheets("Fail").Range("B10").Value & Sheets("Fail").Range("C10").Value & ".xlsx"
```

I have a feeling I'm formatting the code incorrectly. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Adding more info: I'm extracting worksheets from another workbook and creating a temp file. I'm making the temp file the active workbook so I can save it to a different

```
Worksheets("Fail").Visible = True
Worksheets("Fail Screenshot").Visible = True
tempFile = Environ("Temp") & "\Failed.xlsx"
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
wb.Save
wb.Sheets(Array("Fail", "Fail Screenshot")).Copy
Set tempWB = ActiveWorkbook
'TEST is the folder name on my desktop.
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\ME\Desktop\TEST" &  Sheets("Fail").Range("B8").Value & Sheets("Fail").Range("C8").Value & Sheets("Fail").Range("B10").Value & Sheets("Fail").Range("C10").Value & ".xlsx"
```

Comment: Does the concatenation produce a valid path?  Does the folder exist? You are on Windows, right?

Comment: What values are in the cells you're referencing? Are there any characters that aren't valid in file names? Are you trying to save into a folder called TEST, or save direct to the desktop with filenames that begin TEST...?

Comment: Try creating a string and viewing it so get asn idea of what the filenam will be:

    Dim fn As String

    fn = "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\TEST" & Sheets("Fail").Range("B8").Value & Sheets("Fail").Range("C8").Value & Sheets("Fail").Range("B10").Value & Sheets("Fail").Range("C10").Value & ".xlsx"

    MsgBox fn

Comment: Chris - I copied the path directly from the folder. I am using Windows. Werrf - The cell values are all text. I'm trying to save it to a folder named "TEST".

Comment: @Will BeDeleted - I set fn = to my specifications and I have ActiveWorkBook.SaveAs fn, but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the extension ".xlsx" and add fileformat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx
To have a workbook with macros, use fileformat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

Comment: Gave it a shot and I got the same 1004 error. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the CONCATENATE function in a single cell within the active sheet to input the information from the multiple cells. I hid the column with the CONCATENATE function so the user won't see it and it won't print. The information generated from the CONCATENATE function will change based on user entry into a Userform. This is the code I used. Thanks to @SBF for the use of fileformat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook. I used ".xlsx" originally and kept getting the compatibility popup notification.

```
Dim fileName As String
fileName = "C:\Users\ME\Desktop\TEST" & Sheets("Fail").Range("M7").Value &   ".xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=fileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
```